# Prevent node package from causing an error in a different environment

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack

I have browser extension using Webpack and there is one package ([webextension-polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webextension-polyfill)) that throws an error when the script is run outside of the extension environment.

Normally that wouldn't be an issue, but my extension creates a standalone page that can be saved locally by the user and since all the javascript travels with it, this extension specific script throws an error when opened outside of the extension environment.

The only plausible idea I have to get around it is to generate two versions of the bundled javascript. One that imports webextension-polyfill and one that doesn't. Then I could just tell jszip to include that file instead... But that seems a little clunky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a moment of clarity this morning and realized that when the user saves the page locally, I'm already feeding them a separate clean template of a html file, so I ended up getting around the issue by including the script via good old `<script src="browser-polyfill.min.js"></script>` instead of requiring it in the bundle and all I had to do was leave that out of the jsZipped html.